# Open Layers 2.12 and 3 KML GroundOverlay and ScreenOverlay Support

Tags: openlayers, kml, openlayers-3

Does Open Layers 2.12 or Open Layers 3 support KML files with GroundOverlays or ScreenOverlays? KML files with Placemarks work well.

Thanks

Comment: I found the following open issue: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/2941

Answer (score 0):

Open Layers 3 doesn't support KML with GroundOverlay, as you can see on this Issue on GitHub: 
https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/2941

I checked on the internet some Workarrounds you can do:

1. Convert to `OpenLayers.Layer.Image`, acording to https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/16816/does-openlayers-supports-kml-ground-overlays
2. Use Google Earth Web Plugin to convert the KML File (see comment of stevenpetryk on Nov 20, 2014 https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/2941)

Comment: `ol.format.KML` is a vector format and therefore can't support raster overlays.  The image layer suggestion for OpenLayers 2 also wouldn't work correctly as OL2 doesn't support raster reprojection.  However, it is possible with OL3+.   See the working snippets here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082468/kml-openlayers-groundoverlay-element-that-doesnt-have-document-tags-not-loadi/52093649#52093649