# KML/OpenLayers GroundOverlay element that doesn't have <Document> tags not loading onto map?

Tags: openlayers, kml

I have a KML element with no document tags and just  tags like...(with some irrelevant elements removed with ...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<GroundOverlay>
    <name>...</name>
    <description>...</description>
    <Icon><href>...</href></Icon>
    <LatLonBox>
       ...
    </LatLonBox>
</GroundOverlay>
</kml>
```

In OpenLayers, I can't get this to load without document tags around the GroundOverlay. I can however get a place mark that is the root node with no document tags to load fine.

Is there a way to a KML with a GroundOverlay root node into KML that doesn't have document tags? It seems to load fine in other renderers like Google Earth and Cesium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not supported in OpenLayers

https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/2941

Comment: It's not supported by `ol.format.KML` because that's a vector format and Ground Overlays are raster images with specified projections which can only be displayed as raster layers.  OpenLayers will support those, but with no built in support specific for ground overlays the KML document must be parsed in developer code or library function to allow the projections and raster sources to be generated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use ground overlay tiles as the source for an OpenLayers layer.  So far I have only done that by hard coding in the coordinates, tile sizes, tile paths, etc. manually read from the KML and letting OpenLayers calculate the correct projection, and although proj4 does allow rotated projections I have not yet sorted out the maths needed to handle rotations.  I have a demo based on sample data from https://www.dwgwalking.co.uk/garminTryB4Buy.htm  The demo http://mikenunn.16mb.com/demo/dwg-aracena-demo.htm uses east/west coordinates from the top row and north/south coordinates left column and ignores the very small rotation.

**UPDATE**

I've now developed this to a potential library function to parse a KML file for ground overlays and return a layer group of ImageStatic sources and layers.  Rotation is also supported.  The only required parameter is the KML document url.  Supported options are `attributions` and `crossOrigin`.

Here's the previous multi-pverlay demo (with very small rotation) loaded directly from the KML document:

```js
var tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        attributions: [
            'Powered by Esri',
            'Source: Esri, DigitalGlobe, GeoEye, Earthstar Geographics, CNES/Airbus DS, USDA, USGS, AeroGRID, IGN, and the GIS User Community'
        ],
        attributionsCollapsible: false,
        url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
        maxZoom: 23
    })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [tileLayer],
    target: 'map',
    logo: false,
    view: new ol.View({
        center:[0, 0],
        zoom: 2
    })
});

var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();

var group = kmlOverlay.loadUrl(
    'https://www.mikenunn.net/data/dwg/aracena/doc.kml',
    { attributions: 'Copyright David Brawn <a href="https://www.dwgwalking.co.uk" target="_blank">www.dwgwalking.co.uk</a>' }
);

group.getLayers().on('add', function(evt) {
    evt.element.once('change:source', function() {
        if (evt.element.getSource && evt.element.getSource().getProjection) {
            var imageProj = evt.element.getSource().getProjection();
            ol.extent.extend(extent, ol.proj.transformExtent(imageProj.getExtent(), imageProj, map.getView().getProjection()));
            map.getView().fit(extent);
        }
    });
});

group.setOpacity(0.7);
map.addLayer(group);
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>
<script>

kmlOverlay = function() {

function loadUrl ( url,
                   opt_options  // attributions (defaults to undefined), crossOrigin (defaults to 'anonymous')
) {

    var options = opt_options || {};
    var crossOrigin = options.crossOrigin === undefined ? 'anonymous' : options.crossOrigin;

    var group = new ol.layer.Group();

    function addLayer(name, extent, url, rotation) {  // function to maintain context during async img load

        var imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
            title: name
        });
        group.getLayers().push(imageLayer);

        var imageSize = [];
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.onload = function() {
            imageSize[0] = img.width;
            imageSize[1] = img.height;
            imageLayer.setSource(
                source (
                    extent,
                    url,
                    rotation,
                    imageSize,
                    { attributions: options.attributions, crossOrigin: crossOrigin }
                )
            );
        };
        img.crossOrigin = crossOrigin;
        img.src = url;

    }

    var last = url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
    path = url.slice(0, last);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onload = function() {

        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText,'text/xml');

        var elements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('GroundOverlay');

        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {

            var name;
            if (elements[i].getElementsByTagName('rotation').length > 0) {
                name = elements[i].getElementsByTagName('name')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            }
            var href = elements[i].getElementsByTagName('href')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            if (href.indexOf('http:') != 0 && href.indexOf('https:') != 0) {
                href = path + href;
            }
            var north = Number(elements[i].getElementsByTagName('north')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            var south = Number(elements[i].getElementsByTagName('south')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            var east = Number(elements[i].getElementsByTagName('east')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            var west = Number(elements[i].getElementsByTagName('west')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            var rotation = 0;
            if (elements[i].getElementsByTagName('rotation').length > 0) {
                rotation = Number(elements[i].getElementsByTagName('rotation')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            }

            addLayer(name, [west, south, east, north], href, rotation);

        }

    }
    xhr.send();
    return group;

}

function source ( kmlExtent, // KMLs specify the extent the unrotated image would occupy
                  url,
                  rotation,
                  imageSize,
                  opt_options  // attributions, crossOrigin (default to undefined)
) {

    var options = opt_options || {};

    // calculate latitude of true scale of equidistant cylindrical projection based on pixels per degree on each axis

    proj4.defs('EPSG:' + url, '+proj=eqc +lat_ts=' +
                              (Math.acos((ol.extent.getHeight(kmlExtent)/imageSize[1])
                                        /(ol.extent.getWidth(kmlExtent)/imageSize[0]))*180/Math.PI) +
                              ' +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs');

    if (ol.proj.proj4 && ol.proj.proj4.register) { ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4); } // if OL5 register proj4

    // convert the extents to source projection coordinates

    var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:' + url);
    var projExtent = ol.proj.transformExtent(kmlExtent, 'EPSG:4326', projection);

    var angle = -rotation * Math.PI/180;

    function rotateTransform(coordinate) {
        var point = new ol.geom.Point(coordinate);
        point.rotate(angle, ol.extent.getCenter(projExtent));
        return point.getCoordinates();
    }

    function normalTransform(coordinate) {
        var point = new ol.geom.Point(coordinate);
        point.rotate(-angle, ol.extent.getCenter(projExtent));
        return point.getCoordinates();
    }

    var rotatedProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'EPSG:' + url + ':rotation:' + rotation,
        units: 'm',
        extent: projExtent
    });
    ol.proj.addProjection(rotatedProjection);

    ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms('EPSG:4326', rotatedProjection,
        function(coordinate) {
            return rotateTransform(ol.proj.transform(coordinate, 'EPSG:4326', projection));
        },
        function(coordinate) {
            return ol.proj.transform(normalTransform(coordinate), projection, 'EPSG:4326');
        }
    );

    ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms('EPSG:3857', rotatedProjection,
        function(coordinate) {
            return rotateTransform(ol.proj.transform(coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', projection));
        },
        function(coordinate) {
            return ol.proj.transform(normalTransform(coordinate), projection, 'EPSG:3857');
        }
    );

    return new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        projection: rotatedProjection,
        url: url,
        imageExtent: projExtent,
        attributions: options.attributions,
        crossOrigin: options.crossOrigin
    });

}

return {
   "loadUrl" : loadUrl,
   "source"  : source
}

} ();

</script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```

Here's a single overlay demo with very conspicuous rotation taken from https://renenyffenegger.ch/notes/tools/Google-Earth/kml/index

```js
var tileLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
        attributions: [
            'Powered by Esri',
            'Source: Esri, DigitalGlobe, GeoEye, Earthstar Geographics, CNES/Airbus DS, USDA, USGS, AeroGRID, IGN, and the GIS User Community'
        ],
        //attributionsCollapsible: false,
        url: 'https://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}',
        maxZoom: 23
    })
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [tileLayer],
    target: 'map',
    logo: false,
    view: new ol.View({
        center:[0, 0],
        zoom: 2
    })
});

var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();

var group = kmlOverlay.loadUrl(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ReneNyffenegger/about-GoogleEarth/master/kml/GroundOverlay.kml'
);

group.getLayers().once('add', function(evt) {
    evt.element.once('change:source', function() {
        if (evt.element.getSource && evt.element.getSource().getProjection) {
            var imageProj = evt.element.getSource().getProjection();
            ol.extent.extend(extent, ol.proj.transformExtent(imageProj.getExtent(), imageProj, map.getView().getProjection()));
            map.getView().fit(extent, { constrainResolution: false });
        }
    });
});

group.setOpacity(0.8);
map.addLayer(group);
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/css/ol.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- The line below is only needed for old environments like Internet Explorer and Android 4.x -->
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/openlayers/openlayers.github.io/master/en/v5.3.0/build/ol.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.5.0/proj4.js"></script>
<script>

kmlOverlay = function() {

function loadUrl ( url,
                   opt_options  // attributions (defaults to undefined), crossOrigin (defaults to 'anonymous')
) {

    var options = opt_options || {};
    var crossOrigin = options.crossOrigin === undefined ? 'anonymous' : options.crossOrigin;

    var group = new ol.layer.Group();

    function addLayer(name, extent, url, rotation) {  // function to maintain context during async img load

        var imageLayer = new ol.layer.Image({
            title: name
        });
        group.getLayers().push(imageLayer);

        var imageSize = [];
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.onload = function() {
            imageSize[0] = img.width;
            imageSize[1] = img.height;
            imageLayer.setSource(
                source (
                    extent,
                    url,
                    rotation,
                    imageSize,
                    { attributions: options.attributions, crossOrigin: crossOrigin }
                )
            );
        };
        img.crossOrigin = crossOrigin;
        img.src = url;

    }

    var last = url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
    path = url.slice(0, last);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onload = function() {

        var parser = new DOMParser();
        var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xhr.responseText,'text/xml');

        var elements = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('GroundOverlay');

        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {

            var name;
            if (elements[i].getElementsByTagName('rotation').length > 0) {
                name = elements[i].getElementsByTagName('name')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            }
            var href = elements[i].getElementsByTagName('href')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
            if (href.indexOf('http:') != 0 && href.indexOf('https:') != 0) {
                href = path + href;
            }
            var north = Number(elements[i].getElementsByTagName('north')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            var south = Number(elements[i].getElementsByTagName('south')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            var east = Number(elements[i].getElementsByTagName('east')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            var west = Number(elements[i].getElementsByTagName('west')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            var rotation = 0;
            if (elements[i].getElementsByTagName('rotation').length > 0) {
                rotation = Number(elements[i].getElementsByTagName('rotation')[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
            }

            addLayer(name, [west, south, east, north], href, rotation);

        }

    }
    xhr.send();
    return group;

}

function source ( kmlExtent, // KMLs specify the extent the unrotated image would occupy
                  url,
                  rotation,
                  imageSize,
                  opt_options  // attributions, crossOrigin (default to undefined)
) {

    var options = opt_options || {};

    // calculate latitude of true scale of equidistant cylindrical projection based on pixels per degree on each axis

    proj4.defs('EPSG:' + url, '+proj=eqc +lat_ts=' +
                              (Math.acos((ol.extent.getHeight(kmlExtent)/imageSize[1])
                                        /(ol.extent.getWidth(kmlExtent)/imageSize[0]))*180/Math.PI) +
                              ' +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs');

    if (ol.proj.proj4 && ol.proj.proj4.register) { ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4); } // if OL5 register proj4

    // convert the extents to source projection coordinates

    var projection = ol.proj.get('EPSG:' + url);
    var projExtent = ol.proj.transformExtent(kmlExtent, 'EPSG:4326', projection);

    var angle = -rotation * Math.PI/180;

    function rotateTransform(coordinate) {
        var point = new ol.geom.Point(coordinate);
        point.rotate(angle, ol.extent.getCenter(projExtent));
        return point.getCoordinates();
    }

    function normalTransform(coordinate) {
        var point = new ol.geom.Point(coordinate);
        point.rotate(-angle, ol.extent.getCenter(projExtent));
        return point.getCoordinates();
    }

    var rotatedProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({
        code: 'EPSG:' + url + ':rotation:' + rotation,
        units: 'm',
        extent: projExtent
    });
    ol.proj.addProjection(rotatedProjection);

    ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms('EPSG:4326', rotatedProjection,
        function(coordinate) {
            return rotateTransform(ol.proj.transform(coordinate, 'EPSG:4326', projection));
        },
        function(coordinate) {
            return ol.proj.transform(normalTransform(coordinate), projection, 'EPSG:4326');
        }
    );

    ol.proj.addCoordinateTransforms('EPSG:3857', rotatedProjection,
        function(coordinate) {
            return rotateTransform(ol.proj.transform(coordinate, 'EPSG:3857', projection));
        },
        function(coordinate) {
            return ol.proj.transform(normalTransform(coordinate), projection, 'EPSG:3857');
        }
    );

    return new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        projection: rotatedProjection,
        url: url,
        imageExtent: projExtent,
        attributions: options.attributions,
        crossOrigin: options.crossOrigin
    });

}

return {
   "loadUrl" : loadUrl,
   "source"  : source
}

} ();

</script>
<div id="map" class="map"></div>
```